# Can I specify a numpy dtype when generating random values?

Tags: python, numpy, random, floating-point-precision

I'm creating a `numpy` array of random values and adding them to an existing array containing 32-bit floats. I'd like to generate the random values using the same dtype as the target array, so that I don't have to convert the dtypes manually. Currently I do this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype='f')
x += np.random.randn(*x.shape).astype('f')
```

What I'd like to do instead of the last line is something like:

```
x += np.random.randn(*x.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
```

but `randn` (and actually none of the `numpy.random` methods) does not accept a `dtype` argument.

My specific question is, is it possible to specify a dtype for random numbers when I create them, without having to call `astype`? (My guess is that the random number generator is 64 bits long, so it doesn't really make sense to do this, but I thought I'd ask if it's possible.)

Comment: numpy will automatically convert the type of your random array to the type of `x` when you do the operation in-place, there's absolutely no need for `astype`, simply do `x += np.random.randn(*x.shape)`, and see for yourself that `x.dtype` doesn't change.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Q: is it possible to specify a dtype for random numbers when I create them.
>
> A: No it isn't. randn accepts the shape only as randn(d0, d1, ..., dn)

Simply try this:

```
x = np.random.randn(10, 10).astype('f')
```

Or define a new function like

```
np.random.randn2 = lambda *args, dtype=np.float64: np.random.randn(*args).astype(dtype)
x = np.random.randn2(10, 10, dtype='f')
```

If you have to use your code on the post, try this code instead

```
x = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype='f')
x[:] = np.random.randn(*x.shape)
```

This assigns the results of `randn` to the memory allocated by `np.zeros`

Comment: this does not work for the case of scalars (e.g. randn()) because randn will return a float numeric type, not an array - otherwise, basically what I did as well

Comment: This does not seem to work for .astype('i') as it gives a matrix with all elements as 0.

Comment: you can use the usual np.float32 or np.int in astype as well

Comment: @jkhosla integers works fine for me.  note that ~68% of them will be zero.  i.e. it truncates values towards zero, so only ~16% of the distribution will be less than -1 and ~16% above +1

Answer (score 11):

Let me begin by saying that numpy now supports dtypes for random integers. This enhancement can be tracked through [Issue #6790](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6790) on numpy's github. But as of today, this facility is not available for the `gaussian RNG`. I needed this same facility so I wrote this patch for numpy, https://gist.github.com/se4u/e44f631b249e0be03c21c6c898059176

The patch only adds support for generating `float` values and it does not handle other data types, but it might still be helpful to someone.

**UPDATE 27 Sep 2020**

The [numpy.random.Generator](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator) provides RNGs that support the `dtype` keyword for all random variables. E.g. `numpy.random.default_rng().standard_normal(size=1, dtype='float32')` gives `1` standard gaussian of type `float32`.

Comment: This seems to only apply to certain random distributions, Poisson for example doesn't have this argument: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.poisson.html

Comment: poisson distribution is over natural numbers not reals.

Comment: Well, how about uniform then: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.uniform.html

Comment: It seems you have to use a different function called `random`. e.g. `import numpy; numpy.random.default_rng().random(1, dtype='float32')` works. But yes in general your point is right that not all the distributions support it, like `standard_t`

Answer (score 1):

I guess often you can simply use [`randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html), e.g.

```py
np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(256,256,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score -5):

np.random.randn function randomly initializes the array object of a given shape to a "np.float64"
You can find this out yourself by doing as follows:

```
a = np.random.rand(2,3)
b = a[1,2]
print (type(b))
print (type(a))
```

> > > output as follows:

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```